# "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" getting error while facebook post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on facebook post functionality, for that i used facebook php sdk, But it gives me error like "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action", Can anyone please tell me what's issue in this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require '../src/facebook.php';

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '*****';
$config['secret'] = '*****';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
$config['scope'] = 'publish_actions';
$config['redirect_uri'] = 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page';

$fb = new Facebook($config);


// define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
$params = array(
  "access_token" => "*****", // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
  "message" => "This is just testing message",
  "link" => "http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php",
  //"picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
  "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
  "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
  "description" => "Testing description message"
);



// post to Facebook
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/*****/feed', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

die;
```

Comment: In the oauth process, the user have to allow your application to post in his name, then your app will be able to work.
You are seeing this message because the user didn't authorize (yet ?) your app. You have to wait until facebook redirect the user to `redirect_uri` with a token for this user and permissions to post in his name.

Comment: Can you please give me example here ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0#authentication